# iOS previousKeyframe is nil after processing sorted keyframes

Tags: ios, null, keyframe

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tijmK.png)

#### code

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear animations:^{

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration: 0.6 animations:^{
        self.mainTableView.frame = [self.assitTouch convertRect:self.assitTouch.bounds
                                                         toView: self.superview];
        self.mainTableView.layer.cornerRadius = self.assitTouch.layer.cornerRadius;
        self.mainTableView.alpha = 0.5;
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.6 relativeDuration: 0.4 animations:^{
        self.assitTouch.alpha = 0.75;
        self.mainTableView.alpha = 0;
    }];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
        [self.assitTouch startTimer];
        [self removeFromSuperview];
    }
}];
```

#### log

```
2016-03-19 23:36:29.441 AlipayWallet[90581:1325441] previousKeyframe is nil after processing sorted keyframes (
    "<_UIKeyframe: 0x7fdec9874c30>",
    "<_UIKeyframe: 0x7fdec9874c60>"
)
2016-03-19 23:36:29.442 AlipayWallet[90581:1325441] previousKeyframe is nil after processing sorted keyframes (
    "<_UIKeyframe: 0x7fdec986d9b0>",
    "<_UIKeyframe: 0x7fdec986d9e0>"
)
2016-03-19 23:36:29.442 AlipayWallet[90581:1325441] previousKeyframe is nil after processing sorted keyframes (
    "<_UIKeyframe: 0x7fdec9916ba0>",
    "<_UIKeyframe: 0x7fdec9916bd0>"
)
2016-03-19 23:36:29.442 AlipayWallet[90581:1325441] previousKeyframe is nil after processing sorted keyframes (
    "<_UIKeyframe: 0x7fdec9914650>",
    "<_UIKeyframe: 0x7fdec9914680>"
)
```

My code worked well, however, I get this log. 
What doest it mean? 
How can I fix it, Is there any problem if I don't fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add `import QuartzCore` at beginning of file.

Second, before you call `[self removeFromSuperview];`, you should add

`[self.layer removeAllAnimations];`

===

And, if the view is kind of UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell etc, you should add [Swift version, super easy to change to OC version]

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

   // something else

    self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```